# Who to Telnet to access only a prompt?

Tags: telnet, prompt

Is there any host where I can just telnet them and access a prompt?
I'm not looking to hack – just wondering if I needed to.
Let me rephase my question anyone who has an old computer and just lets random people use it as telnet. I know that its crazy and no one would do that but If anyone can find a person like that there on this website!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out http://www.sdf.org.  They appear to have free shell accounts.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you will need:

```
telnet towel.blinkenlights.nl
```